# java Long rounding to 2 decimals absolute value

Tags: java, rounding, long-integer, absolute, decimal

```
long value = Math.round(Math.abs(object.getSomeStuff()/1000));
```

My `object.getSomeStuff()` returns a 3 digit integer value. I want to get the absolute value and also round to 2 digits.

```
Sample Input
123
-257

Sample Output
0.12
0.25
```

I don't exactly want to round it really, I want to truncate it, but that's a minor issue.

What am I doing wrong? I don't think the rounding is being done correctly here.

Sorry if I was not clear. The main issue is rounding which is not happening. I think i'm just seeing an integer value.

Comment: The problem is `object.getSomeStuff()/1000` evaluates to an integer not to double. Try this instead `object.getSomeStuff()/1000.0`

Comment: What exactly doesn't work?

Comment: Formatting tip: Adding four spaces before each line of a paragraph will format the paragraph as a code block. To get an inline block, you can wrap the code ``in `backticks` like these``.

Comment: @ExtremeCoders that is not enough i think, 1 digit first needs to go.

Comment: Edited the question with the issue.

Comment: @Sharat when I said elabourate, I was expecting more like what value you expected vs what you got. "rounding is not happening" is as vague as before.

Comment: Sorry, i'm seeing an integer value meaning if the value is 123, i'm seeing 0. So you're right in your comment.

Comment: To round a double value upto 2 decimal places use `Math.round(double*100.0)/100.0`

Comment: @ExtremeCoders you mean, `Math.round(integer/1000.0*100)/100.0`?

Comment: @JanDvorak Exactly, that is what it evaluates to.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are getting 0 instead of 0.12 due to type issues (the entire operation happening as `Integer`). If so try something like

```
long value = Math.abs((Float)(object.getSomeStuff()/10)/100);
```

Or

```
long value = Math.abs((object.getSomeStuff()/10)/100.0);
```

This should divide by 10 as `Integer` to eliminate one digit, and then divides by 100 as a `Float` to get the final value.